# Control the charging of battery in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I am using a ASUS lap top of model: ASUS VivoBook 15 X510. I have dual booted it with ***Windows 10*** ***Pro*** and ***Ubuntu 20.04***.

In 'ASUS laptops' there is a driver named: 'ASUS Battery Health Charging'. This driver is for controlling the battery charging capacity of the laptop and works only in Widows operating system only. You can see the user interface of the driver from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpSEK.png). There you can see that I have selected maximum life span mode which is only 60% is charging while the laptop is plugged into power. And once I change the settings as I proffered, it does not change in each time I log into the Windows OS.

But when the Ubuntu OS is booted, the driver is not working and it charges up to 100% maxium. ( I know it is not good for the battery health charging up to 100% always). In Ubuntu I could not find any driver to control the level of battery charging.

But I could find this command and I used it.

```
echo 60 | sudo tee /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold
```

This command was successful and after running the command the battery level did not go beyond 60%. The output can be seen from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTeSA.png). But whenever I reboot the computer it again changes the settings to 100% maximum charging. So, I need to enter above code from the terminal at each time I log into the Ubuntu OS in order to limit the charging level to 60% maximum.

I checked for a reliable method in different forums dedicated to Ubuntu also, but could not find a proper solution.

**Can somebody tell me the way to limit the charging of the battery of laptop in Ubuntu OS permanently?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try the following lines of commands from the bash terminal:**

`crontab -e`

- Then select the nano editor
- Add the following command

`@reboot root echo 60 > /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold`

- Then, save and quit

This should configure the battery settings not to exceed the battery charging level beyond 60% when rebooted.

Comment: Thanks for this. I assume this will not work with the laptop plugged in but turned off? Any way to also do that?

Answer (score 0):

Following [How-to-set-battery-charging-threshold-limit-the-charging-in-thinkpad-and-other-laptops-in-linux-unix](https://smarttech101.com/how-to-set-battery-charging-threshold-limit-the-charging-in-thinkpad-and-other-laptops-in-linux-unix/) by  Ajay Yadav :

Identify the files which hold the thresholds, e.g.

```bash
ls --recursive /sys/class/power_supply/BAT*
```

look for filenames like:
`charge_control_end_threshold` and `charge_control_start_threshold`

Create a systemd-service:

```bash
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/battery-charge-threshold.service
```

Paste the following for 85% to start and 90% to stop:

```bash
[Unit]
Description=Set the battery charge threshold
After=multi-user.target
StartLimitBurst=0

[Service]
Type=oneshot
Restart=on-failure
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'echo 85 > /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_start_threshold; echo 90 > /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```bash
# To enable on boot
systemctl enable battery-charge-threshold.service
# To start now
systemctl start battery-charge-threshold.service
```